# Iphone pushViewController release

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

when i call:

```
        ChooseDateView *nextController = [[ChooseDateView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChooseDateView" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

is it necessary to call [nextController release]?

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is neccessary to call

```
[nextController release]
```

otherWise make object as an autorelease

```
ChooseDateView *nextController = [[[ChooseDateView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChooseDateView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to call     [nextController release], otherwise how will the allocated memory be released?

Comment: Yes. Every alloc/retain must be paired with a release/autorelease. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> **You only release or autorelease objects you own.**
>
> You take ownership of an object if you
>   create it using a method whose name
>   begins with “alloc” or “new” or
>   contains “copy” (for example, alloc,
>   newObject, or mutableCopy), or if you
>   send it a retain message.
>
> You use release or autorelease to
>   relinquish ownership of an object.
>   autorelease just means “send a release
>   message in the future” (to understand
>   when this will be, see “Autorelease
>   Pools”).

[Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have allocated the memory, you are the owner of the object. Also after allocation, that object is pushed using pushViewController. So we can safely release the object.
and it is must to do since you own the object.
You can also autorelease it.